# Remove bullet text from string

Tags: vb.net

Is there anyway to remove bullets dragged into a textbox?

```
For example:
o   Task 1
o   Task 2
   Task 3
   Task 4
•   Task 5
```

I have tried `TextBox1.Text.Trim` I have tried `TextBox1.Text.Remove`

No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `String` is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`, LINQ is quite useful for filtering out unwanted characters:

```
' VS2015 supports multi-line strings, so you don't need this hack!
Dim str = <![CDATA[o   Task 1
o   Task 2
   Task 3
   Task 4
•   Task 5]]>.Value

Dim bullets = {"o"c, ""c, "•"c}
Dim str2 = New String((From c In str Where Not bullets.Contains(c)).ToArray())
```

You can expand the `bullets` array to contain any other characters you want to drop.  I don't know of a quick way to identify such characters, although the [`Char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure has some useful `Is...` methods to classify characters.

Comment: This turned out to be the best method that works with my other functions. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.Replace`](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiMnYLJyJLHAhWLLYgKHXI_Bmg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.replace(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=PFXCVYyPN4vboATy_pjABg&usg=AFQjCNF9hBspJuRmLZMN-DnsRs00NqKlfg&sig2=V3oizGd6zOzPUPxXHv2GbQ).

```
"o Task 1 o Task 2  Task 3  Task 4 • Task 5".Replace("o", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and String.Replace you can remove the bullet list characters.

```
Dim text = String.Format("o   Task 1{0}o   Task 2{0}   Task 3{0}   Task 4{0}•   Task 5", Environment.NewLine)

' Replace bullets with empty string.
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(text, "\u2022|\u006F|\uF0A7", String.Empty)

' Replace consecutive multiple space characters with single spaces.
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\ +", " ")

' Trim leading and trailing spaces.
result = result.Replace(vbLf & " ", vbLf).Trim()

' [Optional] Remove unwanted tab breaks if any.
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\t", String.Empty)
```

**Replacing bullets:**
The symbol • is identified by the Unicode value `\u006F`, the symbol  by `\uF0A7` and the symbol • by `\u2022`.

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(text, "\u2022|\u006F|\uF0A7", String.Empty)
```

**Removing unwanted spaces:**
To remove leading and trailing whitespace characters after removing the bullets. You can use `@"\s+"` to remove any kind of whitespace (e.g. tabs, newlines, etc.) and replace them with a single space.

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\ +", " ")
```

**Removing unwanted tabs:**
To remove any occurrence of tabs hanging after removing bullets.

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\t", string.Empty);
```

Output:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
Task 4
Task 5
```